# Replicating data between 2 Mongo replica sets

Tags: mongodb

I'm currently have a mongo replicaset consisting of 1 primary and 2 slaves, that is used by a read-only application. I'm adding a 2nd read-only application that requires access to the same data. I have / am considering using the same RS for both applications, but was wondering if there's a way to create a specific type of configuration with Mongo, that works something like this:

1 x primary, that handles all writes, but is not seen as part of a replicaset by the application, and then 2 sets of read-only secondaries that replicate from primary. Each set of secondary replicates writes from the master. Conceptually, something like:

```
          /----> RS1: |Secondary1|Secondary2|..|SecondaryN|   <--- App1
PRIMARY|=> 
          \----> RS2: |Secondary1|Secondary2|..|SecondaryN|   <--- App2
```

Is this sort of configuration possible at all? What similar architectures could I consider for this use-case?

Thanks in advance.

Brett

Comment: Wait, by your diagram do you mean that App 1 and App2 will write to the primary, also consider that if you have a primary for both you can actually only have one replica set not two

Comment: The apps don't write. A different app all together will update data. For purposes of simplicity, you can think of writes to PRIMARY manually via mongo cli. Those writes are then propogated to 2 replica sets. App1 reads from 1 replica set, App2 reads from the other replica set.

Comment: @Brett I deleted my answer because I totally misunderstood you.

Comment: As Sammaye said you can have one replica set for both application for both applications.

Comment: Indeed in this case you can only have one replica set, if you are looking to create a "nearest" read preference here where by the applications will read from the nearest up member then you can set a nearest read preference in your apps and they will try and pick the one with the lowest latency, but you can't have a primary synch to two sets automatically in MongoDB

Comment: thanks Sammaye, that's more or less what I was looking for. Going to have to try a different approach, going to see what I can do with oplogs, and manually replays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across a way to implement this using mongo tooling:

1. Create a replica set to use as a master. Data updates are written to this RS (represented by "PRIMARY" in the diagram). Do not enable authentication on this host
2. Create 2 replica sets with the same data (completely independent of each other)
3. Schedule regular "mongooplog" runs, using #1 as `from` and each of the RS's for `host` see [the manual](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongooplog/)

Authentication can be set up in the RSs from #2, that only give applications read access to the data.

I haven't tested this yet, but from what I can tell, this approach should work for my objectives - is there anything I've overlooked in this approach?

**edit**

While trying to use this approach, I ran into issues when trying to use mongooplog with authentication on the destination. over and above that, mongooplog doesn't cater for authentication on the source / `--from` rs, and so I wrote a tool to cater for this:

https://github.com/brettcave/mongo-oplogreplay

It supports authentication on both source and destination, as well as replicaset targets.